# How to avoid repetition in SQL when updating multiple columns to the same value?

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I need to update many rows in a table and each row needs to have multiple columns set to the same value. I am using oracle SQL and I am not able to use PL/SQL for this task.

An Example of what I am currently doing:

```
update table set
     col_1 = 'An example column value', 
     col_2 = 'An example column value', 
     col_3 = 'An example column value'
where col_1 = 'original';
```

This works, but requires a lot of tedious repetition and is ugly. Is there any way to reduce this repetition without using PL/SQL?

Comment: How do you identify which rows you want to update? What's the criteria?

Comment: @TheImpaler I am replacing certain string values. and these rows all have matching values in all 3 columns. I know already the strings I am looking to replace so I just use 'where col_1 = 'value' or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not have a really flexible `update`, but it does allow the setting of tuples.  That allows you to use a subquery like this:

```
update table
    set (col1_1, col2_2, col_3) =
         (select x.val, x.val, x.val
          from (select 'An example column value' as val from dual) x
         )
    where col_1 = 'original';
```

Comment: @GordanLinoff This does avoid repeating the string value but it adds an additional subquery. Also it seems this takes quite while longer to run than the original. I guess I was hoping for something more like `update table (col_1, col_2, col_3) = 'An example column value'` but I guess that portion needs to be a subquery?

Comment: @Mox_z . . . I'm surprised this takes much more time.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I guess I must have made some mistake the first time because trying it again and it completes quickly. As far as the reducing repetition and avoiding a subquery goes, is there any way to do both? I guess my main goal here is to reduce typing.

Comment: @Mox_z . . . This reduces typing, definitely.